# Python: How to correctly do this recursion function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am calling a function inside itself 5 times using the function default argument. But, the output is not what I expect as per my understanding.

```
def fun(count=0):
    while count < 5:
        print(count)
        count+=1
        fun(count)
fun()
```

As per my understanding the output should be as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But, it's totally opposite.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a default argument to the function. Why are you looping *and* recursing?

Comment: "As per my understanding the output should be as follows[...] But, it's totally opposite." Your hypotheseis is that you are right and the machine is wrong (most of beginners do). That is the only flaw: 99.999999% of the time the machine is right and does exactly what you instructed it to do. If you're not seing what you expect here, it is because: 1- you did not precisely understood your own code execution flaw according to language rules, 2- did not use a debugger to carefully study your execution flow. Furthermore, you did not provide the actual outputs aside of your expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the function just 5 times, because you are repeating the calls with a `while` loop at every level of the recursive stack.

The outermost call runs from `count = 0` through to `count = 4`, and each iteration calls `fun(count + 1)`, so `fun(1)`, `fun(2)`, `fun(3)`, `fun(4)` and `fun(5)` are *also* called, after printing the `count` value. Those recursive calls each do the same thing, printing the `count` value and then recursing. Only the `fun(5)` calls don't print anything.

Note that **each function call has its own namespace**, the `count` variable for each function execution is independent, it is not shared between the calls. So `count += 1` in a nested function call is not altering the `count` variable in a parent function execution during this time.

Using a default argument to a function doesn't change this; you are only using the default value on the first call with `fun()`; all other calls provide their own value for `count`, so `fun(count)` sets `count` in the recursive call to a specific integer number and the default value `0` is ignored. Remember that in Python, all *names* (including argument names for functions) are [just references to an object](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

So the output for `fun()` becomes a call tree; `count` at each level is independent from `count` variables at nested levels here:

- *`fun()`* (using the default `count=0`)

  - `while count < 5` is true
  - `print(count)` -> **`0`**
  - `count += 1` -> `count = 1`
  - *`fun(1)`*

    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`1`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 2`
    - *`fun(2)`*

      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`2`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 3`
      - *`fun(3)`*

        - `while count < 5` is true
        - `print(count)` -> **`3`**
        - `count += 1` -> `count = 4`
        - *`fun(4)`*

          - `while count < 5` is true
          - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
          - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
          - *`fun(5)`*

            - `while count < 5` is false
            - *function ends*
          - `count = 5` here
          - `while count < 5` is false
          - *function ends*
        - `count = 4` here
        - `while count < 5` is true
        - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
        - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
        - *`fun(5)`*

          - `while count < 5` is false
          - *function ends*
        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `count = 3` here
      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`3`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 4`
      - *`fun(4)`*

        - `while count < 5` is true
        - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
        - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
        - *`fun(5)`*

          - `while count < 5` is false
          - *function ends*
        - `count = 5` here
        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `count = 4` here
      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
      - *`fun(5)`*

        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `count = 2` here
    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`2`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 3`
    - *`fun(3)`*

      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`3`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 4`
      - *`fun(4)`*

        - `while count < 5` is true
        - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
        - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
        - *`fun(5)`*

          - `while count < 5` is false
          - *function ends*
        - `count = 5` here
        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `count = 4` here
      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
      - *`fun(5)`*

        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `count = 3` here
    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`3`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 4`
    - *`fun(4)`*

      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
      - *`fun(5)`*

        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `count = 5` here
      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `count = 4` here
    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
    - *`fun(5)`*

      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `while count < 5` is false
    - *function ends*
  - `count = 1` here
  - `while count < 5` is true
  - `print(count)` -> **`1`**
  - `count += 1` -> `count = 2`
  - *`fun(2)`*

    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`2`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 3`
    - *`fun(3)`*

      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`3`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 4`
      - *`fun(4)`*

        - `while count < 5` is true
        - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
        - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
        - *`fun(5)`*

          - `while count < 5` is false
          - *function ends*
        - `count = 5` here
        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `count = 4` here
      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
      - *`fun(5)`*

        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `count = 3` here
    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`3`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 4`
    - *`fun(4)`*

      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
      - *`fun(5)`*

        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `count = 5` here
      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `count = 4` here
    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
    - *`fun(5)`*

      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `while count < 5` is false
    - *function ends*
  - `count = 2` here
  - `while count < 5` is true
  - `print(count)` -> **`2`**
  - `count += 1` -> `count = 3`
  - *`fun(3)`*

    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`3`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 4`
    - *`fun(4)`*

      - `while count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
      - *`fun(5)`*

        - `while count < 5` is false
        - *function ends*
      - `count = 5` here
      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `count = 4` here
    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
    - *`fun(5)`*

      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `while count < 5` is false
    - *function ends*
  - `count = 3` here
  - `while count < 5` is true
  - `print(count)` -> **`3`**
  - `count += 1` -> `count = 4`
  - *`fun(4)`*

    - `while count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
    - *`fun(5)`*

      - `while count < 5` is false
      - *function ends*
    - `count = 5` here
    - `while count < 5` is false
    - *function ends*
  - `count = 4` here
  - `while count < 5` is true
  - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
  - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
  - *`fun(5)`*

    - `while count < 5` is false
    - *function ends*
  - `while count < 5` is false
  - *function ends*

You **don't need to loop** if all you wanted to do is use recursion to print all the numbers from 1 through to 4. You only need to use `if` to test if you have reached the end of the sequence yet. You also want to increment *before* you test and print, to start your output at `1`:

```
def fun(count=0):
    count += 1         # increment before testing
    if count < 5:      # only print numbers up to 4
        print(count)
        fun(count)     # recursion takes care of the remainder
```

Alternatively, give the function `1` as the default value for `count`:

```
def fun(count=1):
    if count < 5:      # only print numbers up to 4
        print(count)
        count += 1     # increment after testing and printing
        fun(count)     # recursion takes care of the remainder
```

Either way, you now have a call tree that is much shorter, the second version with `count=1` as the default executes:

- *fun()* (using the default `count=1`)

  - `if count < 5` is true
  - `print(count)` -> **`1`**
  - `count += 1` -> `count = 2`
  - *fun(2)*

    - `if count < 5` is true
    - `print(count)` -> **`2`**
    - `count += 1` -> `count = 3`
    - *fun(3)*

      - `if count < 5` is true
      - `print(count)` -> **`3`**
      - `count += 1` -> `count = 4`
      - *fun(4)*

        - `if count < 5` is true
        - `print(count)` -> **`4`**
        - `count += 1` -> `count = 5`
        - *fun(5)*

          - `if count < 5` is false
          - *function ends*
        - *function ends*
      - *function ends*
    - *function ends*
  - *function ends*

Answer (score 1):

You were wrong. Use **If** instead of **While**. It should be:

```
def fun(count=0):
    if count < 5:
        print(count)
        count+=1
        fun(count)

fun()
```

Comment: If it could solve your problem, don't forget to accept :))

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
>>> def fun(count):
...     if count < 5:
...         print(count)
...         count+=1
...         fun(count)
...
>>> fun(0)
0
1
2
3
4
>>> fun(1)
1
2
3
4
>>>
```

You are doing a recursion(a function that calls itself), so you don't need a `while` condition. Always plan for recursion to stop at one point to avoid `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`. Here I am using `if` condition to do that.